How to use a community.sops encrypted jinja template in ansible?
I am using ansible 2.16.10, sops with gpg 3.8.1 and community.sops 1.8.2
I know how to decrypt a sops-encrypted file in ansible using :
lookup('community.sops.sops', 'foo.sops.txt')

And i know how to render a template in ansible,
ansible.builtin.template:
  src: file.j2
  dest: file.conf

But i cannot find a way to combine both, in order to :

have an encrypted template on disk on controller
decrypt the template on the fly
render the template on the target

Any pointers would be appreciated, as i read much documentation without enlightment.
Thanks in advance
